# How do I add more permissions to this policy?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have created a Fargate ECS service that has a execution role with the following policy attached:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_task_execution_role" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    sid     = ""
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

I also need it to be able to access a secret from secrets manager for the image registry credentials so I tried the following:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_task_execution_role" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"]
    resources = ["${resource.aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret.arn}"]
  }
}
```

The Terraform plan works fine but the apply fails with the following error:

> Error: updating IAM Role (dev-fidc-identity-gateway-ecs-role) assume role policy: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource

Any ideas why this might be happening? I have been unable to find the answer.

Comment: There is the trust policy and permissions policy. You are trying to add permissions policy to a trust policy.

Comment: So i'm guessing that I need to do the same again and create a separate role? How can I attach more than one role to the ECS task so it has an execution role and permissions role for accessing the image?

The AWS documentation says this: To provide access to the secrets that you create, add the following permissions as an inline policy to the task execution role

Comment: "So i'm guessing that I need to do the same again and create a separate role?" No, not at all. You just need to attaching some actual permission policies to the role. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have created an ECS Execution Role in Terraform, using the Assume Role Policy in your question, like so:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_execution_role" {
  name = "my_ecs_task_execution_role"

  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_task_execution_role.json
}
```

All you have done so far is create an empty role that ECS can assume, with no permissions assigned to it. To add permissions to the role, you need to attach some policies.

You can attach an existing policy like so:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_execution" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}
```

If you want to create a new policy, and attach it to the role, you would do the following:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_task_secrets_policy" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"]
    resources = ["${resource.aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret.arn}"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "ecs_task_secrets_policy" {
  name   = "my_ecs_task_secrets_policy"
  role   = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_task_secrets_policy.json
}
```